# how to read and write the answer in file i/o

Tags: java, file-io

i have this code i am working on i can read from file ,but i cant save the answer to my txt file .also how do i recall to do other operation on same number .i need a tips on how to do that.

```
 package x;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class x {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //creating File instance to reference text file in Java
        File text = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\testScanner.txt");

        //Creating Scanner instnace to read File in Java
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);

        //Reading each line of file using Scanner class
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
             String line = scnr.nextLine();
            int foo = Integer.parseInt(line);

            System.out.println("===================================");
            System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + line);
            foo=100*foo;
            lineNumber++;
            System.out.println(" foo=100*foo " + lineNumber + " :" + foo);
        }       

    }   

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to help you get a better (and possibly faster) answer.

Comment: If you need tips, look into [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a filewriter to write a file and filereader to write a file. you also need to import java.io. here is an example code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileRead{

   public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

      File file = new File("Hello1.txt");
      // creates the file
      file.createNewFile();
      // creates a FileWriter Object
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
      // Writes the content to the file
      writer.write("This\n is\n an\n example\n"); 
      writer.flush();
      writer.close();

      //Creates a FileReader Object
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); 
      char [] a = new char[50];
      fr.read(a); // reads the content to the array
      for(char c : a)
          System.out.print(c); //prints the characters one by one
      fr.close();
   }
}
```